# Azure Logic app using Workflow Management API

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

```
{
    "name": "12HourHeartBeat",
    "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
    "location": "East US",
    "tags": { },
    "properties": {
        "state": "Enabled",
        "definition": { // Must include at least one trigger

        }
        "parameters": { // Optional

        },
        "sku": { 
            "name": "Standard",
            "plan": { 
                "name": "appserviceplan001", 
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/ServerFarms",
                "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/appserviceplan001
            }
        },
    }
}
```

i am sending Http PUT request to create Logic app .But the created logic app's status is **not enabled** and service plan is also **not showing** !! any suggestions

Comment: I seems you are sending the request to ARM api for deployment? if yes then check the deployment log.

Answer (score 0):

The the logic app is created, one of the initialization steps is to verify existence of the hosting plan that is referenced under the logic app's sku property. In case the hosting plan is not found, the logic app gets disabled.

Are you using a valid hosting plan when doing a PUT on the logic app? You need to provision a hosting plan first before you start deploying your logic apps (if you create your logic app through the azure portal, the create experience allows you to create a hosting plan if one does not exist yet). The hosting plan will not be implicitly created if you just do a PUT on the logic app.